# AS400 - Why token *, ! not valid? What could be the alternate way to run the query using STRSQL - SQL Interactive Session?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

In AS400, How can I run this query using STRSQL?

For the below query getting the following error message instead returning results.

> "Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: FROM INTO."

Code Snippet for Original Query:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
    !SUM(status != 'INACTIVE') OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector) only_inactive,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector ORDER BY last_changed DESC) rn
    FROM test )
              
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE only_inactive AND rn = 1
```

After checking, the query I found the problem is the SELECT statement inside WITH clause. I don't know why this error is there? Unable to find a possible way to solve this issue.

Now, I tried to remove * from the select statement inside WITH clause, somehow avoided this error. After executing my updated query again, I am getting same kind but a different error message.

> Token ! was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + * - ? : DAY INF LAG NAN RID
> ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS.

Code Snippet for Updated Query:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT !SUM(status != 'INACTIVE') OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, 
    service_sector) only_inactive,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector ORDER BY last_changed 
    DESC) rn
    FROM test )
              
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE only_inactive AND rn = 1
```

**I tried:**

Instead of ! token I tried using <> and ¬= but it didn't help me in both cases. When I tried to run my code I encountered the same error message but now with <> and ¬= tokens.

**Expected Result:**

I want to return all records satisfying the logic given in the query with all columns in my table.

Could someone please tell me how to solve this issue?

---

I tried the following updated query just to test whether it's working without ! or NOT token or not.

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT test.*, 
    SUM(status < 'INACTIVE') OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector) only_inactive,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector ORDER BY last_changed DESC) rn
    FROM test )
              
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE only_inactive AND rn = 1
```

I expected this query must have listed some results but this time I get this error message.

> Token < was not valid. Valid tokens: ) ,.

I think the problem is with tokens. Not sure what.

Comment: Replace `!SUM(..)` with `NOT SUM(..)`.

Comment: in sql you can't just use `!` as logical negation operator.

Comment: also `!=` as not equal do work in most dbms but I'll say using `<>` for safety.

Comment: ANSI SQL doesn't allow a single `*` to be combined with anything.

Comment: @Akina I tried using NOT SUM(..) but I think the issue is with the whole query.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or DB2?

Comment: Replace asterisk with columns list. But it is possible that DB2 does not allow to apply logical NOT to non-boolean value - if so then use CASE function instead.

Comment: @jarlh How we can try to fix this issue. Is it feasible? If no is there any room that we can change the query in such a way that it gets executed successfully.

Comment: @jarlh I am using DB2

Comment: Try `SELECT test.*, ...`. However, I'm not sure that DB2 has the ANSI SQL restriction here.

Comment: @jarlh It worked for me using `SELECT test.*`

Comment: I am still facing issues with ! token. My expression is something like this `!(FLD != 'A')`. I tried using NOT also. Unable to think of case condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the query like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT t.*, 
             MIN( status = 'INACTIVE') OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector) as only_inactive,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loc_code, user_id, service_area, service_sector ORDER BY last_changed DESC) as rn
      FROM test t
     )
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=06a963d6bce246072e94cc5f1a31207e) is a db<>fiddle showing that this syntax works in DB2.

Note that the types of the columns should not matter for the syntax error you are seeing.